# Unable to run command prompt programmatically in Windows service

Tags: c#, command-line, windows-services

I have the following code which I'm using to run an executable via the command line programmatically:

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.BitCometDirectory;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
var command = String.Format("/c bitcomet {0} -s --tray", path);
startInfo.Arguments = command;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
var status = process.Start();
```

When I test this code via a console app, it works great.

The goal, however, is to integrate this code into a Windows service.  When I do this and attach the VS debugger to the running service, the service executes without issue/error.  BitComet.exe as well as BitCometService.exe (not sure what that is) also appear in Task Manager.  The command is to open a torrent file and, unfortunately, that is not occurring as the download never begins.  FWIW, `status` is `true`.

When I originally setup the Windows service, I had to create an installer and I set the Account (the account type under which the service will run) to `LocalService` so I wouldn't have to authenticate the service when installing.  I've also tested it with Account set to `User` with the same result.

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:**
I added `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` to my code to log errors, but that always returns an empty string.  When I check the Application logs, however, I see the following Error:

```
Faulting application name: UPNP.exe, version: 1.0.8.11, time stamp: 0x4a9638a4
Faulting module name: UPNP.exe, version: 1.0.8.11, time stamp: 0x4a9638a4
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00013cbf
Faulting process id: 0xe088
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0a1ecc058cc01
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\BitComet\tools\UPNP.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\BitComet\tools\UPNP.exe
Report Id: fe9f1270-0ddf-11e5-b482-10604b472e44
```

I'm not sure what `UPNP.exe` is, but it would appear it's called by `BitComet.exe` which is what my code calls.  Any idea on how to resolve this?  I currently have the service set to log on as my user (rather than Local System or Local Service).

**UPDATE #2**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-06-08T14:13:24.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>136152</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer><<computer info>></Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>UPNP.exe</Data> 
  <Data>1.0.8.11</Data> 
  <Data>4a9638a4</Data> 
  <Data>UPNP.exe</Data> 
  <Data>1.0.8.11</Data> 
  <Data>4a9638a4</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>00013cbf</Data> 
  <Data>1c5c</Data> 
  <Data>01d0a1f5482780b3</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files\BitComet\tools\UPNP.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files\BitComet\tools\UPNP.exe</Data> 
  <Data>85d9245f-0de8-11e5-bb36-10604b472e44</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Need more Information. What does Process.Start() return? Is any exception thrown? How do you know that the program does not run (or doesnt' start and stop with some error) ? (Are you aware that services won't show anything on your screen or as a tray icon?)

Comment: @sgmoore No exceptions.  `Process.Start()` returns `true`.  When the program executes successfully when I run it in a console app, it opens up the BitComet app and downloads a file.  So when I say "the process is not started", I meant the BitComet process doesn't start.

Comment: Any possibility that the paths for the interactive identity differ from the LOCAL SERVICE identity such that the 'bitcomet' executable can no longer be found, thus precluding the process from being created? Or being created, then immediately terminating?

Comment: @DavidW I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about, but the value for `path` is the same when running as a service compared to running in my console app.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the PATH environment variable associated with the user context under which the application is running. Sorry for not making that more clear. The call appears to expect bitcomet to be available somewhere on either the user's or the system PATH.

Comment: Rather than `"/c bitcomet ..."`, use the full executable path: `"/c c:\BitCometDirectory\bitcomet ..."`. It may be that the directory containing your `bitcomet` executable is not in the Local Service user's `PATH` environment variable. `Process.Start()` returns `true` because it was able to start `cmd.exe`, but `cmd.exe` is not able to execute `bitcomet`.

Comment: A Windows service cannot interact with the desktop. It executes in a different session. You can see this in Task Manager if you add the Session ID column in the Details view. It is a bit old but [Sessions, Desktops and Windows Stations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx) contains a good introduction to the concepts. So basically, a child process started by a service will not be visible to the interactive user.

Comment: The `psexec` tool (available from the MS website) can be useful in troubleshooting this sort of problem, because it runs an arbitrary command in the context of a system service.

Comment: @DavidW I'm not using a PATH.  That is the purpose of `startInfo.WorkingDirectory`.  I just tried using the full path and got the same result.

Comment: @JimMischel see my last comment

Comment: @MartinLiversage Interesting.  When I check Task Manager, after the `process.Start()` line runs, `BitComet.exe` and `BitCometService.exe` (not sure what that is...) appear in the Process tab.  Unfortunately, the torrent is not being opened successfully like it is when I run it in my console app because the file download does not begin.

Comment: If `BitComet.exe` starts but doesn't download, then it's quite possible that your LocalService account doesn't have permissions to access the network. You should modify your `ProcessStartInfo` to redirect output (standard output and standard error) to a file so that you can capture any error messages. Also check the Windows event logs to see if there are any notifications about a process trying to do something it doesn't have permissions to do.

Comment: UPNP is a BitComet configuration tool. I'm not familiar specifically with what it does, but if BitComet expects it to fire, and for whatever reason it can't (or fails once it does for insufficient permissions), you may well have inadvertently discovered your problem.

Comment: @DavidW Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that's the entire error log entry for UPNP.exe? Shouldn't there be something that says what the error is? And you should read standard error as well as standard output.

Comment: @im1dermike - that uPNP.exe tool is a curious beast. I initially thought it was a Microsoft configuration tool for PNP clients to advertise themselves as peers related somehow to your referenced torrent, but it is not a standard executable in a "regular" OS location. The fact that it's crashing as you've noted is going to make it a real bear to track down.

Comment: @JimMischel I added the details of the error.  Not much more helpful information.  Additionally, I added `process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` (as well as enabled the redirect of both error types) and that also outputs an empty string.  It would seem that the UPNP.exe issue is the problem at hand because of the timing of the error logs...

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but perhaps this is the issue/fix:

```
var command = String.Format("/c {0}\\bitcomet  -s --tray", path);
```

The idea here is to put the path value into the command fired by CMD. IF that's not where 'path' points, this won't solve the issue.

Comment: See http://wiki.bitcomet.com/bitcomet_command_line.  The path is an argument in the bitcoment command to open a file.  `BitComet <TORRENT_FILE> [–output=OUTPUT] [–silent , [–paused] ] [–tray]`

Comment: I didn't include it.  It's just a valid path to a *.torrent file.  I believe I just discovered the problem.  Will post my answer shortly.

Comment: Good to hear. I'll be very interested to hear the solution! Suspect it's something way out in left field :)

Comment: Ugh.  Perhaps not.  It definitely ran successfully once as a service, but I've been unable to recreate that. :\  The latest possibly lead I added as an update to my post FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to resolve the UPNP.exe error has turned into a black hole.  While ideally I would have all of my torrents (manually and automatically initiated) in the same app, as an alternative, I thought I'd try to wire in a different torrent utility.  I found [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) which is a command-line torrent client.  Within a few minutes, I was able to download a torrent via the service.

I'm not sure what the problem is with BitComet and its UPNP.exe file, or how to resolve it, but this is an alternative I'm going to go with.